# Перегрузка оператора присвоения для элемента матрицы с двумя индексами

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, матрицы

Меня интересует вопрос, как можно перегрузить оператор присвоения в одномерный массив по двум индексам для класса матрицы. Сам массив представляет из себя набор элементов матрицы, записанный построчно, размерности `n*m`. На данный момент у меня готово получение элемента по двум индексам из данного массива через дополнительный proxy-субкласс внутри исходного класса.
Как это выглядит:

```
#include <iostream>

class Matrix {
public: 

    int* arr;
    int n, m;

    Matrix(int sn, int sm=1) {

        n = sn;
        m = sm;
        arr = new int[n*m];

    }

    class Proxy {
    public:

        Matrix* mtx;
        int mi;

        Proxy(Matrix* matr, int i) {
            mtx = matr;
            mi = i;
        }

        int operator[](int j) {
            return mtx->arr[mtx->index(mi, j)];
        }

    };

    Proxy operator[](int i) {
        return Proxy(this, i);
    }

    int index(int i, int j) {

        if (i >= n or j >= m) {
            return -1;
        }

        return i*m + j;

    }
};
```

С таким кодом без проблем вызывается оператор присвоения значения матрицы по индексам в переменную или вывод:

```
Matrix mt(5, 3);
int c = mt[3][2];
std::cout << c << " " << mt[2][3] << std::endl;
```

Но при вызове оператора присвоения по индексам падает ошибка:

```
mt[3][2] = 12;
```

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment: mt[3][2] = 12;

Поэтому единственный способ заполнения матрицы пока только следующий:

```
Matrix mt(3, 2);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        mt.arr[i*3 + j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы еще указать на то, что с С++ я знаком на очень поверхностном уровне, так что если я что-то делаю совершенно не так, как нужно, пожалуйста - укажите на это.

---

Дополню: Дело в том, что нужно будет обращаться к исходной матрице как к транспонированной, не изменяя содержимое. Поэтому мне может понадобиться наличие сразу двух индексов.

Comment: Простите, не могли бы вы пояснить, что вы хотите, более понятно. Ну, написать примерно хотя бы - хочу получить примерно вот такой (псевдо)код. Что такое "*оператор присвоения в одномерный массив по двум индексам для класса матрицы*" - ну никак не соображу...

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос, добавил пример. Для уточнения - есть матрица размерностью n*m. Она помещена в одномерный массив построчно. Мне нужно присваивать значения в эту матрицу по двум индексам - перегрузить оператор присвоения для оператора [][]. Так как такого оператора я не нашел, я нашел вариант сделать перегрузку оператора [] через прокси-класс, в котором тоже перегружен [].

Comment: См. мой ответ. Для этого вам не нужен никакой прокси-класс, надо только перегрузить один оператор `[]`

Comment: Если очень хочется сделать через прокси, поменяйте возвращаемое значение у `Proxy::operator[]` на `int&`

Comment: Спасибо, после установки int& у оператора [] для прокси класса - всё стало работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, что написали вы, достаточно определить один оператор `[]` -

```
int * Matrix::operator[](size_t row)
{
    return arr[row*m];  // Где m  - длина строки
}
```

Применение второго `[]` будет фактически применением к массиву `int`, представляющему соответствующую строку матрицы.

Ну, конечно, можно дописать проверку на выход за границы массива.

Но, откровенно говоря, если уж у вас C++ - то не лучше ли реализовать матрицу как вектор векторов? Типа

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix(n,vector<int>(m));
```

Comment: К сожалению, по заданию матрицу надо реализовать в виде одномерного массива. К слову, ваш метод с определением оператора работает. Спасибо, я думаю вопрос решен.

Comment: В С++  есть класс  std:::valarray, и какраз он  для таких целей  и существует